# WordPress how to prevent URL encoding in URL of taxonomy terms

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy, search, terms

Is it possible to prevent WordPress from encoding URL with terms? I have a sample taxonomy term "iPhone5～iPhone7" and when I use it for the search function, it turns to "iphone5%ef%bd%9eiphone7
" which is not usable when getting the posts for the term. is it possible to prevent url encoding?

thanks in advance.

Comment: ...your code so far please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.